# iOS - AVAssetReader copyNextSampleBuffer can be very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, opengl-es, decoding

I'm trying to decode a video in real time (30 fps) and display /modify it with OpenGL. On an iPod touch, if I decode a video that I took with the camera, decoding a frame can take over 1s, while 30 fps should be 0.03s max. Thus the result is not very good..

Is it possible to achieve that with AVAssetReader ? For example Instagram applies filters (I think GLSL shaders) in real time on a video, and they can even navigate in the video. Instagram works fine on the ipod touch.

The code to decode can be found in the answer here : 
[Best way to access all movie frames in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066117/best-way-to-access-all-movie-frames-in-ios)

And more specifically here : [Hardware accelerated h.264 decoding to texture, overlay or similar in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646657/hardware-accelerated-h-264-decoding-to-texture-overlay-or-similar-in-ios)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my app was just doing too much work on the CPU, I had another process analyzing images. When I removed it, the decoding was really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the very limited information you provided, I have to assume that your video sequence are compressed in the format of YUV and you set settings of AVAssetReader with other format like `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` which forces iOS use hardware acceleration to convert colour space for you, then you feel it slowly. I suggest that no settings to set, just use its original pixel format.